# In SwiftUI, how do I differ the general tap from the button tap in the cell?

Tags: ios, swiftui

I have a list with each item that has a NavigationLink and a cell view in a ZStack.

```
List(inventory.items) { food in
    ZStack {
        NavigationLink(
            destination: InventoryEditionView(food: food, index:inventory.items.firstIndex(of: food)!))
                         {
                         EmptyView()
                         }
                        .disabled(!model.seletedFoodItems.isEmpty)

        InventoryListCell(food: food, model: model)
                        
    }
 }
```

In the cell view, I put a checkmark to allow users to make multiple selections.

```
Button{
            
            if model.isSelected(food: food) {
                model.deselect(food)
            } else {
                model.select(food)
            }

        } label: {
            Image(systemName: "checkmark.circle")
                .frame(width: 44, height: 44)
                .imageScale(.large)
                .foregroundColor(model.isSelected(food: food) ? Color("primary") : Color(.systemGray))
            
        }
```

However, wherever I tap in the cell view, it always triggers the selection. Is it possible to trigger the selection only when the tap is on the checkmark?

Answer (score 1):

you could try using

```
.allowsHitTesting(false)
```

to "turnoff" selection when tapping on the views you
don't want to trigger the selection.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of a button, I just used an image and adjust its color in onTapGesture.

```
 Image(systemName: "checkmark.circle")
                .frame(width: 44, height: 44)
                .imageScale(.large)
                .foregroundColor(model.isSelected(food: food) ? Color("primary") : Color(.systemGray))
                .onTapGesture {
                    if model.isSelected(food: food) {
                        model.deselect(food)
                    } else {
                        model.select(food)
                    }
                }
```